# update struct - d programming language

Tags: struct, d

In initialising a struct, we can go for

```
Foo  a = {1, 7};
```

How do I update values as the program runs?

These forms don't work:

```
a = {2, 9};
a = {fst:2, snd:9};
```

Is the only way the long:

```
a.fst = 2;
a.snd = 9;
```

Seems  inefficient.  What if we have losts of members?

Comment: This works. a = Foo(2,9);

Comment: You should put that in an answer and accept it. Also, does “inefficient” refer to runtime performance or productivity? I can’t imagine it running any slower than the alternative you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a temporary second struct:

```
Foo b = {2,9};
a=b;
```

or use a constructor to create the temporary:

```
a = Foo(2,9);
```